# Why should I use content pipeline

Tags: c#, xna, game-engine, monogame

If I set my images in Content folder to copy always, then I can use them without building it in content pipeline. I simply call them from code like this:

```
testImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("MyImage");
```

and it works without compilation to xnb format. I've noticed that my 46kb image file after compilation have 204kb and I don't know why.

Is there some benefit of compiling it? Or why should I do that?

Comment: When people ask this question they usually get pointed here: http://www.infinitespace-studios.co.uk/general/monogame-content-pipeline-why/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you build a group of files (some PNG files for example), MonoGame stops using the PNGs in the game and starts using its own format, XNB. These files are specially designed for game texture and are, in turn, for efficient. They save the user of your game valuable space on their RAM.

Hope my explanation helps
-GHC